# pH sensor voltage versus pH

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, ph

I am currently in the process of making an ultra-low power pH captor and I'm running in a problem. The voltage I get from my pH probe does not fallow the Nernst equation (which states that the voltage should increase/decrease of 59 mV per pH unit). However when I try it, I only get variation of 1 or 2 mV per pH unit which is extremely low. I can make it work that way, but it's not very efficient and I was wondering of someone would know why that is. I am currently testing on a very simple setup similar to this one:

[image]

I do suspect that the problem comes from the pH probe, but I'd like to hear other people point of view before buying a new one. Does anyone have an idea why my voltage variation is so low? Even though I know it is not necessary, both amplifier are powered by 3.3 and -3.3 V.

Documentation (the datasheet is not accessible to the public) : https://www.phidgets.com/docs/PH/ORP_Sensor_Primer

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add a link to the datasheet for the sensor. Also, explain where you are measuring the voltages. A good place to start would be between output of A and the 1.25 V reference rail.

Comment: If your circuit is "similar" to the one shown, you should tell us exactly how it is different. Better yet, include a schematic of your circuit, not some different circuit from elsewhere.

Comment: How was the circuit constructed? PH probe circuit construction requires resistance and leakage control. Provide a picture of the circuit or PCB drawing

Comment: have you used a guard around the Vin+ to the opamp?

Comment: Alright, I added a picture of the new testing montage really quickly, I apologize for the poor drawing. I know the fact that I do not have a temperature sensitive resistance will be an error issue later on, but I should still have around 59 mV per pH unit with this simple setup.

Comment: What exact opamp are you using?  Note the input impedance of the opamp in your first circuit "1 teraohm or greater."  Does your opamp meet that requirement?  Is your **pcb** clean enough to meet that requirement?  Is the cable connecting your probe to your PCB up to that standard?

Comment: I am using the LM358 as prototype setup, so it is not yet on PCB. In commun mode, I have 10 GOhm of input resistance. But as I am looking at other pH captor setup, this does not seem to be the issue...

Comment: The data sheet for the LM358A shows 45 nA typical input bias current, but pH electrodes typically produce low pA currents.

Comment: Your new circuit is (A) nothing like the one from Linear/Analog, and (B) totally not gonna work. Just for a start of what's wrong, you have two op-amps outputs tied together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response is a bit late, but the problem came from the fact that the operational amplifier did not have high entry impedance. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good, so just like I said in my comment! Glad it is working!

Comment: You can accept your own answer.